Bluetooth - How to remove pairing information on Python3
I want to remove pairing information on Python3.
I know how to remove it on bluetoothctl.
The command is bluetoothctl remove xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
But, I want to use only Python3.
My device is Raspberry PI.
I use BlueZ.
The source code to remove is below.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import dbus

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"), "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager")

path = [str(p) for p in manager.GetManagedObjects().keys()]

# get the device path to remove 
path = list(filter(lambda s: re.match(r"/org/bluez/hci0/dev[_0-9A-F]+$", s), path))

for p in path:
  # I wish this method exists.
  # manager.RemoveObject(dbus.String(p))
  pass

I checked Bluetooth SIG, BlueZ and D-Bus(freedesktop).
Thanks.

The BlueZ adapter interface has a RemoveDevice method which is what bluetoothctl uses to remove devices.
The API information is at:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/org.bluez.Adapter.rst
An example of how to remove all the devices is below:
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"),
                         "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager")
dongle = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/org/bluez/hci0"),
                        "org.bluez.Adapter1")

devices = [obj for obj, info in manager.GetManagedObjects().items() 
           if 'org.bluez.Device1' in info]


for dev in devices:
    dongle.RemoveDevice(dev)

